# ошибка в консоли Cannot find module "../reading-list/page" - js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Запускаю сервер, и в консоль выводит это, пытался найти ответ но ничего не нашел, можно ли как-то это убрать?

```
Error in event handler: Error: Cannot find module "../reading-list/page"
at eval (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:36:13280)
at Object.eval (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:36:13369)
at t (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:3:107)
at Object.eval (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:15:10190)
at t (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:3:107)
at Object.eval (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:15:10125)
at t (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:3:107)
at Object.eval (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:3:238)
at t (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:3:107)
at eval (sandboxed-default-document-end.js:3:195)
```

В HTML стандартная разметка, через !, JS файл пустой, всего 2 файла в папке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 4):

У меня появилась такая же ошибка только что.
В моём случае, это проблема в расширение Vimbox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратите внимание, вы дали ответ. На ответ вам никто не ответит. [Задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и сошлитесь на текуший, если есть взаимосвязь. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, удалите.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ» пожалуйста удалите.

Comment: Вообще говоря, если проблема действительно в этом расширении - то это вполне себе ответ)

Comment: поддерживаю @vp_arth , это вполне себе ответ. и лично мне он сэкономил время )